# convert pdf to transparent png

Tags: php, pdf, png, imagemagick, transparency

I'm using ImageMagick to convert a pdf file to a png (thumbnail) image, and it works well. I'm wondering whether it's possible to convert the pdf, which has a white background, to a png file with a transparent background (i.e. set all the white pixels to transparent).

This is the PHP code i'm currently using (which results in a png file with a white background):

```
/* Open first page of PDF file */
$im = new imagick($pdf_filepath . '[0]');

/* Scale */
$im->thumbnailImage($width, $height);

/* Convert to png */
$im->setImageFormat('png');

/* Save file */
$result = $im->writeImage($thumbnail_filepath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/#mask_creation

I think you will have to create it to GIF first and then back to png if you wish.

Comment: Thanks... looks like I have only scratched the surface of ImageMagick. I will look into it.